# Can't write to process's input

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I'm trying to make a C# function that make a database dump from MySQL server. And as you may know, MySQL asks for a password like this:
[image]

So here's what I did:

```
public static bool BackupDatabase(string filename)
{
    try
    {
        string mysqldumpdir = @"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqldump.exe";
        string user = "root";
        string password = "root";
        string databases= "hrsmarttest7";
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = mysqldumpdir,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            Arguments = string.Format("--user {0} --password --databases {1} --result-file=\"{2}\"", user, databases, filename),
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };
        var mysqldump = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo, EnableRaisingEvents = true };
        mysqldump.Start();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        mysqldump.StandardInput.AutoFlush = true;
        mysqldump.StandardInput.Write(password+"\n"); // this doesn't do the job !!!
        mysqldump.WaitForExit();
        mysqldump.Close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //RecordException(e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I execute this function, the process starts and waits for the user to write a password but `mysqldump.StandardInput.Write` doesn't write it and I have to kill the process to end my program.

Please help.

Comment: There is probably a good reason that mysql.exe does not allow standard input as source for the password. A password is, as you know, a bit special.

Comment: This question is vastly too broad.

Comment: What do you mean ?? @Drew

Comment: Not that it has too many possible answers, but that any answer would be huge. Moreover, unrelated, it seems to me that it would be a disservice to to anyone to solve this. It would irresponsibly put them and future readers at risk

Comment: What ?? First, the password thing is an approach that you can just ignore. Second, the main problem is with C# and processes' input stream and solving this would really help a lot of future readers. @Drew

Comment: You are asking how to bypass a stream blocking i/o routine for passwords. The very mechanism put in to protect the stackholders with their data. Anyway, there are links above to read and in other places that we can suggest about narrowing down questions that get to be too broad if they do. You can get someone to reopen this questions too. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this to your .my.cnf file

```
[mysqldump]
user=root
password=root
```

It is safer than passing the password on the command line and/or storing it in source code. However, as this file is your client's machine you should create a read-only user for backing up your databases rather than using root. The backup user only needs the following permissions:

```
GRANT LOCK TABLES, SELECT ON *.* TO 'BACKUPUSER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

See this [blog](http://bencane.com/2011/12/12/creating-a-read-only-backup-user-for-mysqldump/) by Benjamin Cane for further details:

Comment: This is not safe ! I can't do that.

Comment: Storing your password in source code or calling an external application with a password is less safe. You need to set restrictive permissions on the folder containing .my.cnf.

Comment: The app is deployed on a client's machine in which he would have all the rights, plus the password is not stored anywhere it's calculated based on a license string (a long story)

Comment: What stops them writing a mysqldump.exe console app to print out the password ? I hope you are obfuscating your C# code so they can't decompile it.

Comment: Yes I'm obfuscating the code, and they can't do anything with mysql since they won't have the password so they won't have access to the databases related to the app (the app have control of the root user).

Comment: I can replace mysqldump.exe with my own and capture the MySQL credentials.  You should create a read-only user that has just enough permissions to run the backup. You should be able to save that user  and its password safely in .my.cnf.

Comment: Obfuscation is not protection. Please apply better security. Create a new mysql account that has only the rights that this process needs. Give the username and password of that account to the client. Check out ILSPY - it will decompile any .NET software and show all strings inside.

Comment: @Jaco Thank you for the hint, I will work on that ;)